# Airflow Pipeline to read CSVs and load into PostgreSQL

Tags: python, postgresql, airflow

So, I am trying to write an airflow Dag to 1) Read a few different CSVs from my local desk, 2) Create different PostgresQL tables, 3) Load the files into their respective tables. When I am running the DAG, the second step seems to fail.

Below are the DAG logic operators code:

```
AIRFLOW_HOME = os.getenv('AIRFLOW_HOME')

def get_listings_data ():
    listings = pd.read_csv(AIRFLOW_HOME + '/dags/data/listings.csv')
    return listings

def get_g01_data ():
    demographics= pd.read_csv(AIRFLOW_HOME + '/dags/data/demographics.csv')
    return demographics
    
def insert_listing_data_func(**kwargs):
    ps_pg_hook = PostgresHook(postgres_conn_id="postgres")
    conn_ps = ps_pg_hook.get_conn()

    ti = kwargs['ti']
    insert_df = pd.DataFrame.listings

    if len(insert_df) > 0:
        col_names = ['host_id', 'host_name', 'host_neighbourhood', 'host_total_listings_count', 'neighbourhood_cleansed', 'property_type', 'price', 'has_availability', 'availability_30']

        values = insert_df[col_names].to_dict('split')
        values = values['data']
        logging.info(values)

        insert_sql = """
                    INSERT INTO assignment_2.listings (host_name, host_neighbourhood, host_total_listings_count, neighbourhood_cleansed, property_type, price, has_availability, availability_30) 
                    VALUES %s
                    """

        result = execute_values(conn_ps.cursor(), insert_sql, values, page_size=len(insert_df))
        conn_ps.commit()
    else:
        None

    return None

def insert_demographics_data_func(**kwargs):
    ps_pg_hook = PostgresHook(postgres_conn_id="postgres")
    conn_ps = ps_pg_hook.get_conn()

    ti = kwargs['ti']
    insert_df = pd.DataFrame.demographics

    if len(insert_df) > 0:
        col_names = ['LGA', 'Median_age_persons', 'Median_mortgage_repay_monthly', 'Median_tot_prsnl_inc_weekly', 'Median_rent_weekly', 'Median_tot_fam_inc_weekly', 'Average_num_psns_per_bedroom', 'Median_tot_hhd_inc_weekly', 'Average_household_size']

        values = insert_df[col_names].to_dict('split')
        values = values['data']
        logging.info(values)

        insert_sql = """
                    INSERT INTO assignment_2.demographics (LGA,Median_age_persons,Median_mortgage_repay_monthly,Median_tot_prsnl_inc_weekly,Median_rent_weekly,Median_tot_fam_inc_weekly,Average_num_psns_per_bedroom,Median_tot_hhd_inc_weekly,Average_household_size) 
                    VALUES %s
                    """

        result = execute_values(conn_ps.cursor(), insert_sql, values, page_size=len(insert_df))
        conn_ps.commit()
    else:
        None

    return None
```

And my postgresQL hook for the demographics table (just an example) is below:

```
create_psql_table_demographics= PostgresOperator(
task_id="create_psql_table_demographics",
postgres_conn_id="postgres",
sql="""
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS postgres.demographics (
        LGA                             VARCHAR,
        Median_age_persons              INT,
        Median_mortgage_repay_monthly   INT,
        Median_tot_prsnl_inc_weekly     INT,
        Median_rent_weekly              INT,
        Median_tot_fam_inc_weekly       INT,
        Average_num_psns_per_bedroom    DECIMAL(10,1),
        Median_tot_hhd_inc_weekly       INT,
        Average_household_size          DECIMAL(10,2)
        );
""",
dag=dag)
```

Am I missing something in my code that stops the completion of that `create_psql_table_demographics` from running successfully on Airflow?

Comment: You posted partial code and also didn't post the error traceback so it's very hard to assist you.

Answer (score 4):

If your Postgresql database has access to the CSV files,
you may simply use the `copy_expert` method of the PostgresHook class (cf [documentation](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/providers/postgres/hooks/postgres.py#L117)).
Postgresql is pretty efficient in loading flat files: you'll save a lot of cpu cycles by not involving python (and Pandas!), not to mention the potential encoding issues that you would have to address.